# Is the set of integers of the form $a/(b+c)+b/(a+c)+c/(a+b)$ computable?

Tags: nt.number-theory, computability-theory, diophantine-equations

The starting point of this question is the observation that the smallest positive integers $a,b,c$ satisfying

$$\frac{a}{b+c} + \frac{b}{a+c} + \frac{c}{a+b} = 4$$

are [absurdly high](https://web.archive.org/web/20170813162605/https://plus.google.com/+johncbaez999/posts/Pr8LgYYxvbM), namely <sub>$$(154476802108746166441951315019919837485664325669565431700026634898253202035277999,$$ $$36875131794129999827197811565225474825492979968971970996283137471637224634055579
,$$ $$
4373612677928697257861252602371390152816537558161613618621437993378423467772036)
.$$</sub> This leads to the following general question: Is the set $C\subseteq {\mathbb N}$ defined by $$ C = \{n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}: (\exists a,b,c \in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}):\frac{a}{b+c} + \frac{b}{a+c} + \frac{c}{a+b} = n\}$$
computable? (As user [Watson](https://mathoverflow.net/users/84923/watson) points out in the comment section below, $C$ contains no odd numbers. It would also be great to see an even number $\geq 6$ not contained in $C$.)

Comment: Oops thanks - will remove that second question!

Comment: A quick heuristic comment: for each $n$, the existence of such $a, b, c$ corresponds to the existence of a solution to a degree-$3$ Diophantine equation in $3$ variables; and this is, I believe, a bit beyond what is generally known to be decidable. So I suspect that there will be no *general* reason why this set is computable; rather, if it is computable (which I extremely strongly suspect it is), the proof is likely to be a corollary of a complete characterization of these $n$s, which will not use any computability theory.

Comment: I don't have the time to look into the details, but from a cursory glance at [this quora answer](http://goo.gl/wgYSvn) it looks like the problem amounts to deciding whether a certain elliptic curve has solutions over $\mathbb{Q}$. Now IIRC there is an algorithm for that (find solutions locally and try to globalize) *provided* [Ш is finite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tate%E2%80%93Shafarevich_group), which is conjecturally always the case. So I think conjecturally your set is indeed computable.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402537/find-integer-in-the-form-fracabc-fracbca-fraccab/409450 and Bremner and Macleod, An unusual cubic representation problem, Annales Mathematicae et Informaticae 43 (2014) 29-41, http://ami.ektf.hu/uploads/papers/finalpdf/AMI_43_from29to41.pdf

Comment: [Here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227713) is explained why $C$ doesn't contain any odd number.

Comment: So we're half done!

Comment: This is somewhat similar to the question which natural numbers $n$ are *congruent numbers* (i.e. the area of a right-angled triangle with rational sides), which comes down to asking whether the elliptic curve $E_n \colon y^2 = x^3-n^2x$ has positive rank over $\mathbb Q$. In this case, there is a conjectural answer (Tunnell's Theorem, conditional on the BSD conjecture), which relies on the fact that the $E_n$ are all quadratic twists of a fixed curve. The question asked here is likely to be harder, since the resulting curves are not twists, and there is the positivity condition. -->

Comment: (continued) Note that there are odd $n$ for which the associated elliptic curve has positive rank, but does not have rational points on the component that contains the positive points. (IIRC, $n = 19$ is an example.) This gives an additional twist to the question.

Comment: Cross-posted to https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/39383/computability-of-a-weird-set

Comment: Also discussed at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/184956/apple-banana-pineapple-problem

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/264754/solution-to-a-diophantine-equation/275193#275193